# SQL group by from one table and max from another

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

I have 3 tables `ab`, `bcd` and `c`. Now I want to group by `a_id` from `ab` table and select max `date` from `c` table. This is what I tried till now:

```
select ab.a_id, bcd.d_id, c.val, max(c.date) as date
from tableab ab, tablebcd bcd, tablec c
where ab.b_id = bcd.b_id
and bcd.c_id = c.c_id
group by ab.a_id
```

Its working without error, but not giving correct results. I don't know much SQL so I may be missing something simple. Thanks for your help!

Comment: What is the result you are getting and what is the result you are expecting?

Comment: Sample data with expected result in text format would be helpful .

Comment: @aRvi I want one row per `ab.a_id` (the one with max `c.date`) but I am getting multiple rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from your existing query, a straight-forward approach is `row_number()` (available in MySQL 8.0 only).

```
select * 
from (
    select 
        ab.a_id, 
        bcd.d_id, 
        c.val, 
        row_number() over(partition by ab.a_id order by c.date desc) as rn
    from tableab ab
    iner join tablebcd bcd on  ab.b_id = bcd.b_id
    inner join tablec c on bcd.c_id = c.c_id
) t
where rn = 1
```

`row_number()` ranks records having the same `a_id` by descending `date` - you can then use this information to filter the table.

Note that I rewrote the query to use standard, explicit joins rather than old-school, implicit joins (with a comma in the `from` clause): this syntax from decades ago should not be used in new code.